# Can I add the mediaelement.js player interface after the standalone mediaelement object is built?

Tags: javascript, mediaelement.js

I'm working with code that uses Mediaelement.js to build the standalone player object without the player user interface:

var player = new MediaElement('player', { .....

Can I (easily) add the visual user interface that comes with the player, after the player object is already built?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. It sounds like you want to use the mediaelement-and-player.js to build the player controls, but that you can't do that on initialization. Is that correct? Some more example code detail may be useful.

Comment: Yes, some back-end code (which I don't have access to) loads mediaelement.js and builds the player without the interface. I'd like to add the interface without destroying and re-building it.

Comment: That's a tough one. The player controls are very complex and a lot of work has been done to make sure they have good accessibility. It'd be hard to recreate that outside the library. Without the controls, however, the player is just a JavaScript object, so you won't lose a lot by destroying it and reinitializing.